# Javascript Regex adding an attribute within <img> and style=" "

Tags: javascript, html, regex

So I'm working on this RegEx for an extension I'm building onto Dreamweaver

I've got this snippet to work to search within the  tags to find if there ISN'T a display:block attribute - and subsequently add it.

That's works, but now I need it to search within the inline style tag within the img tags.

i.e.

```
<img style="border:0px;" src="" alt=""/>
```

Here is my regex snippet:

```
if (displayBlock.checked)
            {
                fixIt('<img((?:(?!display:block|/>).)*)/>','<img$1 display:block/>')
            }
```

if you also have some good reference material for RegEx, that would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Mike.

Answer (score 4):

Using regex on HTML elements is typically a bad practice to use.

Why not just iterate the style property?

This iterates ALL the image tags, but you can modify the selector as you wish. Iterate the tags, check to see if the display is undefined, or, falsy, and then add the style property value.

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("img"), function(element) {
    if (!element.style.display) {
        element.style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

Here's a faster, but less secure, but more simple to understand for loop version!

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    if (!x[i].style.display) {
        x[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hah! because I'd no idea how to write that :P I'm still quite a newbie to JS - let me try make this work and I'll get back to you! thank you for your post though

Comment: The loop I used it a bit advanced, but it's one of many ways to iterate a collection of elements. But the style property of the element object is the main focus here. I hope it works!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance I have no idea how to alter this to make it work within my if checked statement. I get what's happening on like 2 and 3 just the first one throws me off.

Comment: That's Duchess to you, Woodhouse. Now go get me some sand for your dead little eyes.

Comment: I keep getting document.querySelectorAll is not a valid function. so I'm not sure what to set up for a func but I'm sure I'll get it to work eventually. thanks again for your help!

Comment: @MikeVanStan ah, that must be because you're working with DreamWeaver and not a webpage -- my fault. You want the equivalent there of selecting elements from however DW does it

Comment: I can only use getElementByID within DW selecter AFAIK and that's not going to work for me :/ I'm going to leave the answer open and try do it via regex. I know it's bad practice - but DW is lame ): once again thank you for trying!